# jQuery simple hover effect lost on appended elements (by infinite scroll)

Tags: jquery, scroll, hover, infinite

I'm developing a wordpress theme which appends the posts with infinite scroll and that has a simple jQuery snippet to hide/show the post titles, when the post is being hovered:

```
$('article').mouseover(function() { 
    $(this).next('h2.subtitled').show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).next('h2.subtitled').hide();
});
```

So basically every post ('article') is followed by its title ('h2.subtitled'), which is initially hidden (via display:none;) and fixed positioned at the browser's bottom. This seems to work well so far, but once the infinite scroll loads new elements:

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#main');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : 'article'
  });

  // update columnWidth on window resize
    $(window).smartresize(function(){
      $container.isotope({
      });
    });

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '.pagination',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '.pagination a.next',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : 'article',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
      }
    },
    // call Isotope as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
    }
  );


});
```

The hover effects doesn't work anymore on the newly appended elements. I kind of get, that the hover function was already fired and the new elements don't even know that they were supposed to hover something, so I tried to repeat the hover function in the callback of the infinite scroll:

```
function( newElements ) {
        $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) );

        $('article').mouseover(function() { 
                $(this).next('h2.subtitled').show();
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $(this).next('h2.subtitled').hide();
        });
    }
```

Which does not work, they new elements still do not hover. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the basic HTML structure:

```
<div id="main">
    <article class="hubbub">
        //article content
    </article>
    <h2 class="subtitled">
        //h2 content
    </h2>
</div>
```

Okay, sorry, I figured the problem, it lies somewhere else. Thanks so far… As the  follows the  and the infinite scroll only grabs the  element as an itemSelector, there where no 's in the appended elements. So, I need the  elements on a fixed place at the bottom of the border. As soon as I put them inside of the  which has {position: relative;}, the  elements are fixed related to the parent , on each 's bottom. Is there a way, to keep the  inside of the , but still have them fixed on the browser's bottom? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) in jQuery:

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#main').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'article', function() { 
    $(this).next('h2.subtitled').toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <article>here is some text</article>
    <h2 class="subtitled">h2 header</h2>

    <article>article 2: here is some text</article>
    <h2 class="subtitled">article 2: h2 header</h2>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/YTuXY/4/)

<strike>I am assuming is `article` is a CSS class and so you need the selector `.article`.</strike> Binding this way you do not need to re-fire the function after the ajax update, you attach the "watch" on the parent container which then "listens" for all newly attached child elements too.

EDIT:
After [further reading](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseover-and-mouseenter-in-jquery/), you can use the `mouseeneter` and `mouseleave` events since they have the correct (lack of) event bubbling otherwise the "mouse in" event will fire too often for your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't. The 'h2.subtitled' elements are not removed on .mouseout and as well, the function doesn't launch on the infinite scroll appended elements.
'article' is a tag-element, not a class and worked to be called without the preceding period.

Comment: My bad, I updated to code sample. But you are saying it still doesn't work? You only need to call the above function once (immediately after `var $container = $('#main')` would be fine), not when each elements are loaded

Comment: @user2355143 I missed the `mouseout` event. I modified the code.

Comment: Hello, the script now works on the first elements, but still not on the appended elements after the infinite scroll load. Same as before, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the code in between my last post (and added a jsFiddle demo). Do you have a sample of the HTML?

Comment: Hey, it still does not work on the appended elements, here is a simplified structure of my HTML:
`<div id="main">
<article>
Content of article
</article>
<h2 class="subtitled">Content of h2</h2>
</div>`
The h2 has to be outside of article and follow it, I changed your code from .children to .next to make it work on that structure, but like I said, still not for the appended elements...

Comment: You need to call document to parse new appended content: `$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#main article', function() { `

Comment: @lolo Why? You should always attach to the nearest selector when possible

Comment: @user2355143 I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/YTuXY/2/ Since I can't Ajax load data I simulated it, but you can see it still works. You must have something else wrong somewhere else, inspect the HTML once it has been loaded into your document to make sure it is inserted into the correct element and the markup is as expected.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I figured the problem, it lies somewhere else. Thanks so far… As the <h2> follows the <article> and the infinite scroll only grabs the <article> element as an itemSelector, there where no <h2>'s in the appended elements. So, I need the <h2> elements on a fixed place at the bottom of the border. As soon as I put them inside of the <article> which has {position: relative;}, the <h2> elements are fixed related to the parent <article>, on each <article>'s bottom. Is there a way, to keep the <h2> inside of the <article>, but still have them fixed on the browser's bottom? Thanks!

Comment: The H2 is displayed in the normal flow of the document, if you want it fixed position then you can position it relative to `#main` using absolute position and `top\bottom\left\right` http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/YTuXY/4/ If this is your only issue then please open a new question and don't forget to upvote and accept this one :)